# CoreMLHelpers : Create binary data of image for multiarray conversion

Tags: ios, swift, multidimensional-array, coreml

We are referring this for CoreMLhelpers for below for converting UIImage to MultiArray and vice versa.

Link: https://github.com/hollance/CoreMLHelpers.

We found below reference of comment.

// cat.bin contains cat.jpg saved as doubles in the range [0,1) with shape
// (3, 360, 480). Load this binary data into a new MLMultiArray object.

Hence, we used custom image and tried to create .bin file as below.
But we are not getting desired output, we can see the cat image with multiple color mixed with green in shade.

Can anyone throw some light here, to convey what can be correct ?

Appreciate your response !

```
import UIKit

func createBinary() -> MLMultiArray? {
    guard let image = UIImage(named: “cat.jpg”) else {
      fatalError(“Failed to load image”)
    }
    // Convert image to pixel data
    guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else {
      fatalError(“Failed to get CGImage from resized image”)
    }
    let width = 480
    let height = 360
    let bytesPerPixel = 4
    let bytesPerRow = width * bytesPerPixel
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little.rawValue | CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue
    var pixelData = Array<UInt8>(repeating: 0, count: width * height * bytesPerPixel)
    guard let context = CGContext(data: &pixelData, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo) else {
      fatalError(“Failed to create CGContext”)
    }
    context.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))

    // Convert pixel data to binary data
    var binaryData = NSMutableData()

    for y in 0..<height {
      for x in 0..<width {
        let index = y * width * bytesPerPixel + x * bytesPerPixel
        var red = Double(pixelData[index]) / 255.0
            var green = Double(pixelData[index + 1]) / 255.0
            var blue = Double(pixelData[index + 2]) / 255.0
        binaryData.append(UnsafeRawPointer(&red), length: MemoryLayout<Double>.size)
        binaryData.append(UnsafeRawPointer(&green), length: MemoryLayout<Double>.size)
        binaryData.append(UnsafeRawPointer(&blue), length: MemoryLayout<Double>.size)
      }
    }
    // Verify binary data shape
    let expectedShape = (3, 360, 480)
    let actualShape = (3, height, width)
    guard expectedShape == actualShape else {
      fatalError(“Unexpected binary data shape: \(actualShape), expected: \(expectedShape)“)
    }
    // Done
    print(“Binary data size: \(binaryData.count) bytes”)
    let ptr = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mutating: (binaryData as NSData).bytes)
    return try? MLMultiArray(dataPointer: ptr,
                 shape: [3, 360, 480],
                 dataType: .double,
                 strides: [NSNumber(value: 360*480), 480, 1])
  }
```